# How to detect change of pagination in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

Is there any event to check data table pagination changing numbers in vuetify? How does event `update:pagination` of data table work?

Answer (score 6):

I usually load data from a backend server and I haven't had any problems  implementing the update:pagination event like this:

```
<v-data-table ... @update:pagination="updatePagination" />
```

Then I create the method to be invoked when pagination gets updated:

```
methods: {
  updatePagination (pagination) {
    console.log('update:pagination', pagination)
  }
}
```

Note that updatePagination method will be "automatically" invoked when the data-table component is mounted and, of course, after you click the pagination arrows.

Answer (score 4):

If you use vuetify 2.x, code like bolow:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="bookHeaders"
    :items="books"
    :server-items-length="totalCount"
    :options.sync="options"
></v-data-table>
```

In Data you need declare:

```
data() {
        return {
            options: {},
            totalCount: -1,
   }
}
```

So you need implement in Watch and Methods:

```
watch: {
        options: {
            handler() {
                this.fetchBook()
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        fetchBook: async function() {
            const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options

            let data = await bookService.GetBookBase(sort, page, itemsPerPage)
            this.books = data.Books //suppose this is the list of items you return
            if (data.TotalCount) {
                this.totalCount = data.TotalCount //suppose this is the total of items you return
            }
            //...You can implement other things such as sortBy, sortDesc....
        },
    }
```

My API use await, but you can using Promise because they are equivalent.
All action like select page, next-pre page (sort if you want) will call API with params in this.Options.

This is documentation full [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort).
Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I had a similar situation and your answer has helped me to achieve this. But I need to know whether the user has click next/previous page. Is there any property/event to check this

Answer (score 3):

> Vuetify makes pagination very easy.Just read carefully the documentation and you will find anything related.

If you use v-data-table [paginate and sort server side](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-server) vuetify says:
*If you’re loading data from a backend and want to paginate and sort the results before displaying them, you can use the total-items prop. Defining this prop will disable the built-in sorting and pagination, and you will instead need to use the pagination prop to listen for changes.*

So when the pagination changes get data from backend and the corresponding code is:

```
watch: {
  pagination: {
    handler () {
      getDataFromBacked()
        .then(data => {
          this.items = data.items
          this.totalItems = data.total
        })
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <v-data-table v-if="products"

   :headers="headers"
      :items="products.data"
      :items-per-page="products.per_page"
      :server-items-length="products.total"
      :options.sync="options"
      :page.sync="page"
       hide-default-footer
      :loading="loading"
      class="elevation-1"

    >

<v-pagination v-if="products"
    v-model="page"
    :length="products.last_page"
  ></v-pagination>
```

.....
data: () => ({
options: {})}
.....

```
 watch: {
    options(val) {
   console.log("beautiful object",val)
   this.loading = false
    },
 
  }
```